# PyCharm opening files from two locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am using parent folder as external library in `PyCharm.`

When I select `main.py file` it is referenced from current directory and external directory as well.

I don't want it to reference from External Libraries section. I have also marked `todo` as the Source root.

[image]

Comment: In Settings, Editor, File Types you can hide files and folders, and this prevents them from being indexed. That might help, I don't know.

Comment: I don't want to remove file association. When, I click at main.py it should open reference from the todo folder and not from the external library(bottom section)

Comment: "I am using parent folder as external library"

@meallhour Could you please clarify how you setup it this way? From the screenshot it looks like `todo` folder is inside a virtual environment, which sounds like something one should not be doing.